# How to ensure enum and array have same entries at compile?

Tags: c, arrays, enums, embedded

This is for an embedded application that runs at a low level on a uC. Another part of the system requires parameters to be set and the local uC needs to maintain a list of parameters. Each parameter consists of an 8 bit ID and an 8 bit value. The ID's begin at 0x70 due to memory limitations at the other end.

In order to keep the memory usage as low as possible I have implemented the parameter store as an array containing the IDs and Values for all the writable parameters. There is then an enumerated list of these parameters in the header file to allow other parts of the application to access the parameters.

Is there any way to ensure that the enum list and the array of parameters have the same entries in the same order? I have documented the code fairly thoroughly (not all included in the extracts) but I would like to put in some form of check at compile time to ensure that the list and array match up.

Another thing I'm not sure of is if this is the most efficient way of implementing this. I need to be able to iterate through the parameters in order to transmit them to the other part of the system and I need to use as little memory as possible.

From `parameters.h`:

```
/*******************************************************************************/
/* IDs for all parameters must be defined                                      */
/* Defaults only need to be defined for rut-time writable parameters           */
/* All parameters must have an ID define                                       */
/* Writable parameters must also have:                                         */
/*    * DefaultValue define                                                    */
/*    * Entry in ParamIndex                                                    */
/*    * Initialesed default entry in Parameters (contained in C file)          */
/*    * If min and max values are not 0x00 and 0xFF then define those too      */
/*******************************************************************************/

// Parameter IDs - All parameters need this defining
#define Param_ActualTemp_ID                         0xE0
#define Param_OperationMode_ID                      0xE1
#define Param_MaintenanceModePID0_ID                0xE5
#define Param_MaintenanceModePID1_ID                0xE6
#define Param_FirmwareVersionL_ID                   0xEB
#define Param_FirmwareVersionH_ID                   0xEC
#define Param_SerialNumberL_ID                      0xED
#define Param_SerialNumberH_ID                      0xEE
#define Param_SerialNumberHH_ID                     0xEF
#define Param_MaxTemperature_ID                     0xFC
#define Param_NULL_ID                               0xFF

// Parameter Default Values - All writable parameters need this defining
#define Param_NULL_DefaultValue                     0xFF
#define Param_OperationMode_DefaultValue            0
#define Param_MaintenanceModePID0_DefaultValue      0xFF
#define Param_MaintenanceModePID1_DefaultValue      0xFF
#define Param_MaxTemperature_DefaultValue           0x54

typedef struct
{
  const uint8    id;
        uint8    value;
} PARAMETER;

// Parameter Index, any writable parameters need an entry here
// Used as array index for parameters[], do not edit existing values
typedef enum
{
  Param_NULL = 0,
  Param_OperationMode,
  Param_MaintenanceModePID0,
  Param_MaintenanceModePID1,
  Param_MaxTemperature,

    /* Additional values must be entered above this line */
  Param_NUMBER_OF_IMPLEMENTED_PARAMS
} ParamIndex;

extern PARAMETER parameters[];
```

From `parameters.c`:

```
PARAMETER parameters[] = {
  { .id = Param_NULL_ID,                 .value = Param_NULL_DefaultValue},
  { .id = Param_OperationMode_ID,        .value = Param_OperationMode_DefaultValue},
  { .id = Param_MaintenanceModePID0_ID,  .value = Param_MaintenanceModePID0_DefaultValue},
  { .id = Param_MaintenanceModePID1_ID,  .value = Param_MaintenanceModePID1_DefaultValue},
  { .id = Param_MaxTemperature_ID,       .value = Param_MaxTemperature_DefaultValue}
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track with the `Param_NUMBER_OF_IMPLEMENTED_PARAMS`. Unfortunately you cannot use this as an array size, because that only guarantees that the array doesn't have more initializers than the enum. It does not protect against the array having too few initializers.

The way to ensure this is to make a static assertion of the enum size versus the array size. Keep the array declaration as `PARAMETER parameters[]` and then do

```
_Static_assert(Param_NUMBER_OF_IMPLEMENTED_PARAMS == sizeof(parameters)/sizeof(*parameters), 
               "Array initializer list does not match enum");
```

---

The standard keyword `_Static_assert` is however only available in C11, and the standard macro `static_assert` is only available in C11 and C++. On older compilers, you will have to invent it yourself. For example:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr) {typedef uint8_t S_ASSERT[(expr) ? 1 : 0];}
```

This will give a cryptic "cannot declare an array with size zero" compiler error if the assert fails.

---

Ordering can be ensured by using designated initializers for the array items:

```
PARAMETER parameters[] = {
  [Param_NULL_DefaultValue] = { .id = Param_NULL_ID, .value = Param_NULL_DefaultValue},
  ...
```

Designated initializers does not prevent duplicates, but in case of duplicate entries only the last one will be used (and you typically get a compiler warning). Such duplicate entries will not affect the array size.

Comment: I can't seem to get a static assert macro working with my compiler (derived from gcc 4.1) but having the designated initializers is a great idea that I wasn't aware of. I've added that in and I'll just make sure that the other developer on this project is aware of what I've done. I'm probably going to be the one doing the maintenance on this code in the future anyhow.

Comment: @RobbG Static assert was introduced with C11, which in turn was introduced somewhere around gcc 4.8. You should be able to use my home-brewn static assert macro on any C compiler though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Param_NUMBER_OF_IMPLEMENTED_PARAMS` as the array size. That will at least lead to the compiler reacting if you have to many elements in the array initializer list.

There is however no (standard and portable) way to warn that you're not initializing all elements. All elements you don't initialize will be "zero" initialized.

There is *definitely* no way of ensuring order, not at compile-time.

There might be static analyzer tools which might help you. And of course rigorous code-reviews.

Comment: Thanks, I was mainly looking for if there was a built in way of doing that. I think with the documentation it should be fairly clear what's going on and what needs adding if we need to change the list in the future. I'll be looking at static analysis tools in the future so I might add that to the list of things I look for in them.

Comment: Of course you can ensure this at compile time, with static asserts. This is a well-known scenario and work-arounds have existed for decades before static asserts were included in the standard.

Comment: @RobbG See my answer for how to ensure this automatically in standard C. No need for manual review nor static analysers.

Comment: @Lundin Damn... I was thinking about static assert, but didn't know they existed for C11. Unfortunately compilers for embedded environments tend to lag behind quite a lot so the "workaround" static assert probably have to be used.

Comment: @RobbG Static asserts as suggested [and shown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41060165/440558) by Lundin does offer a solution for *both* problems: The size and the ordering. One static assert to ensure the size, and one for each element to ensure the ordering.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The embedded compilers seem to finally catch up, they are starting to support basic C11 features. And of course GCC had C11 for years. As for the ordering, see the update in my answer.

Comment: @Lundin Wish I could upvote you twice. :) I think it's time I went back to C for some fun learning. :)

Comment: @someprogrammerdude That's one of the things I like about embedded programming, c is a wonderful if unforgiving language with plenty of quirks and interesting features to keep you on your toes. Excellent for learning with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generator macros, like these ones.
When you modify the PARAM_BLOCK, the enum and the array are build automatically.

```
#define PARAM_BLOCK(GEN_FUNC)  \
  GEN_FUNC(Param_NULL_ID, Param_NULL_DefaultValue)         \
  GEN_FUNC(Param_OperationMode_ID, Param_OperationMode_DefaultValue) \
  GEN_FUNC(Param_MaintenanceModePID0_ID, Param_MaintenanceModePID0_DefaultValue) \
  GEN_FUNC(Param_MaintenanceModePID1_ID, Param_MaintenanceModePID1_DefaultValue) \
  GEN_FUNC(Param_MaxTemperature_ID, Param_MaxTemperature_DefaultValue) \

#define GENERATE_PARAM_ARRAY(paramId,paramValue)   { .id = paramId, .value = paramValue },
#define GENERATE_PARAM_ENUM(paramId,paramValue)          paramId,

typedef enum
{
  GENERATE_PARAM_ENUM(PARAM_BLOCK)
    /* Additional values must be entered above this line */
  Param_NUMBER_OF_IMPLEMENTED_PARAMS
} ParamIndex;

PARAMETER parameters[] = {
    GENERATE_PARAM_ARRAY(PARAM_BLOCK)
};
```

But perhaps you could simplify your parameter array, as you have an ordered array by id, you don't need the id at all.

```
#define GENERATE_WRITE_PARAM_ARRAY(paramId,paramValue)   paramValue,
uint8 writeable_parameters[] = {
        GENERATE_WRITE_PARAM_ARRAY(PARAM_BLOCK)
    };
```

Comment: I avoided this solution on purpose, since so-called "X macros" produce awfully ugly code. There should be no need to use them in this case. "X macro" solutions are always the very last resort and should be avoided if possible.